# Visual Studio 2008 resx files editor

Tags: visual-studio, resx

I need to make some translations of external application forms (I try to add a new language support). I have only form's resx files. 
Can you recommend any simple tool which allows me to translate form's texts (only texts if it's possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRes.exe, it is included with the SDK.  Run it from the Visual Studio command prompt.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict editing only to visible control texts (prevent editing controls position, variable names...)?

Comment: Not really.  Nor would you want to.  Other languages can be very wordy and need larger controls to fit the text.  Which is the reason that Location and Size are localizable properties.